# I want to find if a list in a list of lists has a keyword. If it does I want to print the list. How would I go about this?

Tags: list, web-scraping, indexing, beautifulsoup, element

I've been creating a web scraper for some local car dealerships. I currently have multiple lists of lists containing the car information. For example:

```
CarList1 = [['Toyota Corolla', 'P12453', '25 000 KM', '$15 000'], ['Honda Civic', 'QT6758', '55 000 KM', '$1400']]
```

I want to be able to quickly search through a large list of cars. Using user input, I would like to check if each list within the list of lists contains a keyword.

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
UserInput = Corolla 

Output>>> ['Toyota Corolla', 'P12453', '25 000 KM', '$15 000']
```

I tried using the example set by this website:
[https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-search-a-list-of-lists-in-python#:~:text=Use%20a%20list%20comprehension%20to,is%20True%20and%20False%20otherwise](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-search-a-list-of-lists-in-python#:%7E:text=Use%20a%20list%20comprehension%20to,is%20True%20and%20False%20otherwise).

I couldn't get it to work unfortunately. If you have any ideas as to how I would be able to reach my goal, I'd love the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
carlist = [['Toyota Corolla', 'P12453', '25 000 KM', '$15 000'], ['Honda Civic', 'QT6758', '55 000 KM', '$1400']]

element = 'Toyota Corolla'

for list in carlist1:                                                       
    if element in list:                                                   
       print(list)
```